# TypeError: No Matching declaration found after variable lookup

Tags: contract-deployment

I am adding a MintToken Function to a standard ERC20 token. I have added the appropriate owner contract and the contract I want to deploy inherits that ownership. However, I keep getting this error.

```
function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner {
    balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
    totalSupply += mintedAmount;
    Transfer(0, owner, mintedAmount);
    Transfer(owner, target, mintedAmount);
}

TypeError: No matching declaration found after variable lookup.
    balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
    ^-------^
```

Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you declaring `balanceOf`? Perhaps you used a different name?

Answer (score 1):

balanceOf is a function that returns the balance of a given address.
You should be able to modify the balances by using the actual state variable which is balances[address];

Here's the implementation of the mint function from Open Zeppelin:

```
/**
   * @dev Function to mint tokens
   * @param _to The address that will receive the minted tokens.
   * @param _amount The amount of tokens to mint.
   * @return A boolean that indicates if the operation was successful.
   */
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner canMint public returns (bool) {
    totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_amount);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
    Mint(_to, _amount);
    Transfer(address(0), _to, _amount);
    return true;
  }
```